# How to initialize a gensim model with the vocabulary from another model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I'm training some embeddings on a large corpus.  I gather from `gensim`'s documentation that it builds the vocabulary before beginning training.  In my case, building the vocabulary takes many hours.  I'd like to save time by re-using the vocabulary from the first model.  How can I do this?  the `.build_vocab` method can't take the `vocabulary` object from another model.

Here's a dummy example:

```
from gensim.models import FastText, Word2Vec
sentences = ["where are my goats", "yay i found my goats"]
m1 = Word2Vec(sentences, size  = 3)
m2 = Word2Vec(size = 4)
m2.build_vocab(m1.vocabulary) # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1981) ("Reusing Vocabulary built with scan_vocab is impossible") I believe this isn't possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

`build_vocab()` says to survey a corpus of texts & configure the model's vocabulary from that corpus – so it doesn't take another model's internal state.

But you could either:

- save the model after vocabulary-discovery, for later reuse from that point on; or
- just directly modify any model however you'd like, to mimic another's state

For example, consider an initial session:

```
vocab_model = Word2Vec(size=3)
vocab_model.build_vocab(sentences)
vocab_model.save('vocab_initialized_but_untrained_model.w2v')
```

Now, you could immediately continue to train that model...

```
vocab_model.train(sentences, total_examples=vocab_model.corpus_count, epochs=10)
```

...and then perhaps do other work with, and `.save()`, that trained model, too.

But then also, later, you could simply re-load the vocabulary-initialized model and do other tinkering/training:

```
prior_model = Word2Vec.load('vocab_initialized_but_untrained_model.w2v')
// more operations on that model
```

And further, you can always directly modify the parts of a model however you'd like – though in some cases this may break the existing code's expectations about the model's state. For example:

```
source_model = Word2Vec.load('original_model.w2v')
new_model = Word2Vec(size=4)
new_model.vocabulary = source_model.vocabulary
```

(You probably need to copy over some other fields as well, to mimic all the effects of the 1st model's initialization, and perhaps re-trigger the final steps of the `build_vocab()` with your new `size`/modes. See the source code & especially the methods having to do with `_weights(` or `prepare_`.)

Comment: Indeed, I would need to do a bit more than the initial steps that you suggest.  I get a "need to build the vocab" error when I try to train after transfering over the vocabulary object.

Comment: So: look at the line of code generating that error, see what state it's checking for, copy that over too.